# Get max and min from fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
First:
id | title 
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc

Second:
id | first_id | one | two | three | four
1  |    1     | 3   | 1   | 4     | 6
2  |    2     | 4   | 4   | 1     | 2
3  |    3     | 1   | 2   | 3     | 4
```

and i would like show:

```
id | title | min | max 
1  | aaa   |  1  | 6
2  | bbb   |  1  | 4
3  | ccc   |  1  | 4
```

Is this possible with SQL? How? :)

Comment: i would like get all fours fields (one, two, three and four) and get for this values - min and max value

Comment: yes, that was clear.. now.. can you do it for one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Tom's answer, this would be the best to do.

Anyway, and shame on me :

```
SELECT f.id, f.title
 MIN(LEAST(s.one, s.two, s.three, s.four)) as min,
 MAX(GREATEST(s.one, s.two, s.three, s.four)) as max
 FROM First f
 INNER JOIN Second s on f.id = s.first_id
 GROUP BY f.id, f.title
```

you can remove MIN and MAX (and Group by) if Second can't have many rows with same first_id.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt what's complicated ? We don't know if Second can have multiple identical ids

Comment: The usage of MIN and MAX, JOIN and GROUP, all in a single query. Seems rather unnecessary

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt that's why I put my last phrase in answer !

Answer (score 2):

**Normalize your database**. With your current setup it's not impossible but definitely not recommended.

-edit-
If you must, you can use [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

-edit2-

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.title,
    LEAST(b.one,b.two,b.three,b.four) min,
    GREATEST(b.one,b.two,b.three,b.four) max
FROM first a
INNER JOIN second b ON a.id=b.first_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `UNION`. try this one out:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, MIN(b.c) `Min`, MAX(b.c) `Max`
FROM First a INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT first_id, `one` c FROM `Second`
       UNION
    SELECT first_id, `two` c FROM `Second`
       UNION
    SELECT first_id, `three` c FROM `Second`
       UNION
    SELECT first_id, `four` c FROM `Second`
) b on a.id = b.First_ID
GROUP BY a.id
```

**[SEE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85a68/1)**

Comment: why downvoted? i've demonstrated the other way of solving the problem without using `LEAST` and `GREATEST`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select first_id,F.title ,MIN(num) [min],MAX(num) [max] from (
select first_id,[one] [num]from [Second]  union all
select first_id,[two] [num]from [Second]  union all
select first_id,[three] [num]from [Second]  union all
select first_id,[four] [num] from [Second] )[Second]
join [First] F
on Id=first_id
group by first_id,F.title
```