# Skip 0 and NULL in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My previous problem and solution:

[Get max and min from fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392195/get-max-and-min-from-fields)

This working OK, but i would like skip 0 and NULL in this examples.

For example:

```
First:
id | title 
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc

Second:
id | first_id | one | two    | three | four
1  |    1     | 3   | 0      | 4     | 6
2  |    2     | 4   | 4      | 1     | 2
3  |    3     | 1   | NULL   | 3     | 4
```

this should show me:

```
id | title | min | max 
1  | aaa   |  3  | 6
2  | bbb   |  1  | 4
3  | ccc   |  1  | 4
```

and **not**:

```
id | title | min | max 
1  | aaa   |  0  | 6
2  | bbb   |  1  | 4
3  | ccc   |  0  | 4
```

In which example from my previous question is the best way to implement skip 0 and NULL?

Comment: Why didn't you post the query you're using at the moment?

Comment: Like in the previous question, the remark must be made that you would make your life substantially easier if you would just **normalise** your database. If you do that, it would be a simple WHERE clause.

Comment: Is `first_id` a unique column, or can there be duplicate `first_id`'s?

Answer (score 1):

Pop these into your clause

```
SELECT 
    f.id, 
    f.title
    MIN(LEAST(greatest(coalesce(s.one,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.two,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.three,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.four,0),1))) as min,
    MAX(GREATEST(greatest(coalesce(s.one,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.two,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.three,0),1), greatest(coalesce(s.four,0),1))) as max
FROM 
    First f
        INNER JOIN Second s
        on f.id = s.first_id
GROUP BY 
    f.id, 
    f.title
```

You can use `coalesce(fieldName, 1)` to turn a null into a 1.

Again, as said in your previous question, this is HORRIBLE use of a query to force an answer. You should be changing the layout of the database.

Edit: I have nutted out the data you want, but before you look at it, be aware that if one of my colleagues wrote a script like this, he would be sacked on the spot. This is HIDEOUS and should NOT BE USED.

```
select
    f.id,
    f.title,
    (select min(z.myVal) from
        (
select
    b.id,
    b.first_id,
    b.one as myVal
from
    second b
where
    b.one is not null
    and b.one > 0
union
select
    b.id,
    b.first_id,
    b.two as myVal
from
    second b
where
    b.two is not null
    and b.two > 0
union
select
    b.id,
    b.first_id,
    b.three as myVal
from
    second b
where
    b.three is not null
    and b.three > 0
union
select
    b.id,
    b.first_id,
    b.four as myVal
from
    second b
where
    b.four is not null
    and b.four > 0
        ) z
    where
    f.id=z.first_id) as miniVal,
    greatest(
        coalesce(s.one,0),
        coalesce(s.two,0),
        coalesce(s.three,0),
        coalesce(s.four,0)  
    ) as maxiVal
from
    first f,
    second s
where
    f.id=s.first_id
```

output Data

```
+------+-------+---------+---------+
| id   | title | miniVal | maxiVal |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|    1 | aaaa  |       3 |       6 |
|    2 | bbbb  |       1 |       4 |
|    3 | cccc  |       1 |       4 |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Running this query made me throw up a little in my mouth. That's how wrong it is to write SQL like this.

Comment: but in which answer from previous question i can use this clause? now if i add this WHERE then this clause skip line where fieldname < 1, but i would like instead skip - get min value without 0

Comment: Modified the query to suit your purpose, but it made sad. You really should change your database model.

Comment: thanks, but now if i null in database then as min i have 0. this is wrong. For ID: 1 - this show me as MIN 1, but should be 3

Comment: No, a `greatest(coalesce(fieldName, 0),1)` will work as follows: If fieldName is null, it turns it to a zero, otherwise it leaves it alone, then it determines what is greater, the value or 1 and returns that. If the field is 3, it will return 3.

Comment: your solution return for ID:1 - 1(min) and 6(max) - but should return (3)min and 6(max)

Comment: @PeterVorkter Okay, got your code that returns the data as per your example. That said, it is horrible and you SHOULD LISTEN when many of the folks here and myself are telling you to change your data model. This is horrible code to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

While seemingly clunky, this solution should work:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.title, MIN(b.num) AS min, MAX(b.num) AS max
FROM 
    first a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT first_id, one AS num FROM second UNION ALL
    SELECT first_id, two FROM second UNION ALL
    SELECT first_id, three FROM second UNION ALL
    SELECT first_id, four FROM second 
) b ON 
    a.id = b.first_id AND 
    b.num IS NOT NULL AND 
    b.num > 0
GROUP BY 
    a.id, a.title
```

What this does is it actually gets each number column into its own row, but ***only*** the numbers that are not null and > 0. Before the `GROUP BY`, the result of the `LEFT JOIN` would look something like:

```
id  |  title  |  num
---------------------
1   |  aaa    |  3
1   |  aaa    |  4
1   |  aaa    |  6
2   |  bbb    |  1
2   |  bbb    |  2
2   |  bbb    |  4
2   |  bbb    |  4
3   |  ccc    |  1
3   |  ccc    |  3
3   |  ccc    |  4
```

Then by the groupings of each `first` (`GROUP BY a.id, a.title`), we can use the `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate functions on the `num` column to extract minimum and maximum values per `first` group:

```
id  |  title  |  min  |  max
----------------------------
1   |  aaa    |  3    |  6
2   |  bbb    |  1    |  4
3   |  ccc    |  1    |  4
```

In the case that a `first_id` had all four columns having `NULL`'s or `0`'s, the min and max values would show up as `NULL` due to using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` as I believe this is would be a better behavior for your situation:

```
id  |  title  |  min  |  max
----------------------------
4   |  ddd    |  NULL |  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
WHERE COLUMN IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN <> 0;
```

Comment: ok, but this not show me line with ID 1 and 3 because is clause where > 0. Instead this i would like get minimum value without 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL()`:

```
WHERE IFNULL(fieldname, 0) != 0
```

Comment: maybe is function IFZERO then get previous MIN values?

Comment: You only want to "include" rows, where a specific field is not 0 or NULL. IFNULL(field, 0) converts all NULL-values to 0. != 0 filters out 0-rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to nest the LEAST expressions:

```
LEAST(
    NULLIF(one,0),
    LEAST(
        NULLIF(two,0),
            LEAST(
                NULLIF(three,0),
                LEAST(
                    NULLIF(four,0),
                    null ))))
```

**Edit** I just looked it up. The LEAST function takes multiple arguments:

```
LEAST( NULLIF(one,0), NULLIF(two,0), NULLIF(three,0), NULLIF(four,0))
```

**Edit 2** I see you want both min and max. Obviously you'd just change LEAST to GREATEST or MIN to MAX as needed.

This may be more straightforward or you may not have a handy least function.

```
SELECT
    f.id, f.title,
    (
        SELECT MIN(NULLIF(val, 0))
        FROM
            (
                SELECT one AS val UNION ALL
                SELECT two UNION ALL
                SELECT three UNION ALL
                SELECT four
            ) AS vals
        ) 
    ) as minval

FROM First f INNER JOIN Second s on f.id = s.first_id
```

You haven't specified if it's possible for all four columns to be null/0. We may need to tweak for that case.

Comment: Your sample data suggest that an inner join is sufficient. Some of the other solutions are using outer joins and groupings that I don't think are necessary. I have only skimmed the other solutions, so apologies if I have restated something already pointed out.